# Populating a List - Python assigns index and gives error

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a solution to count the number of occurrences of each letter in a `string` and return a `dict`.

```py
    def count_characters(in_str):
        all_freq = {}
        for i in in_str: 
            if i in all_freq: 
                all_freq[i] += 1
            else: 
                all_freq[i] = 1
        return all_freq

   count_characters("Hello")
```

It works.

I am trying to understand how Python automatically assigns each letter as the `key` to the `dict` - its not explicitly assigned. I replace the `null` dictionary assignment with a `list` and expect to get just the frequency, without the letter.

```py
     def count_characters(in_str):
            all_freq = [] 
            for i in in_str: 
                if i in all_freq: 
                    all_freq[i] += 1
                else: 
                    all_freq[i] = 1
            return all_freq

     count_characters("Hello")
```

I get an error.

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

My question is:

1. How does each letter get automatically assigned as the key?
2. How can I return just the numbers as a list - without the letter?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 1):

> How does each letter get automatically assigned as the key?

You are doing it explicitly in `all_freq[i] = 1`.  Here, `i` contains a letter (though I think the variable could be named better — `i` typically stands for an idex of some sort, which this isn't).

> How can I return just the numbers as a list - without the letter?

You could still build a dictionary and then return `list(all_freq.values())`.  Though, if you do that, how would you know which letter each count corresponds to?

This is probably not relevant for your exercise, but the standard library already has a class for doing this sort of counting:  [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: To explain a little bit more, `i` contains a letter because `in_str` is a string, and `for i in in_str:` repeatedly assigns elements of `in_str` to `i`, and the elements of a string are (well, close enough for our purposes at the moment) the characters it's made up of.

Answer (score 0):

1. List are indexing with integer, in your second exemple you use dictionary synthax with a list, that why python complain.
2. You can use count method

```py
def count_characters(in_str): 
    all_freq = [] 
    for i in in_str:
        all_freq.append(in_str.count(i))
    return all_freq 
count_characters("Hello")
```

Edit : I agree with @NPE comment

> You could still build a dictionary and then return list(all_freq.values()). Though, if you do that, how would you know which letter each count corresponds to?
>
> This is probably not relevant for your exercise, but the standard library already has a class for doing this sort of counting: collections.Counter.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple when we use built-in methods of dictionary like .keys(), .values()

Example:

```
def count_char(string):
    dict = {}
    count = 0
    for i in string :
        if i in dict.keys():
            dict[i] +=1
        else:
            dict[i] = 1
    for j in dict.values():
          count += j
    print(dict)
    print(count)
```